# How to centrally align my text under loader for all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>
      #loader {
        position:absolute; 
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
        border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 5px solid #1976d2;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
       -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      }
      
      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
      
      @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body id="body">
    <div class="loadingcontainer">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="loadingMsg" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color:black; top: 50%; left: 50%;   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; position:absolute;">Making stuff up. Please wait... </div>
  </div>
```

there is a loader and a text below, kindly help to centrally position text below/under the loader for all screen-sizes. How to style/make changes in the above code?

Comment: What do you mean by "centrally position text"? Screenshot/description of desired result would be helpful.

Comment: Adjusting #loadingMsg margin by -25px won't center it. It needs to be adjusted by half the width of #loadingMsg to get centered horizontally.

Comment: For center the text, you can remove the css "left" and add "width: 100%; text-align: center;"

Comment: basically centrally position it under the pre-loader, for any screen-size. I tried using top:60 % and left:45%. but this wont work for smaller screen size or apps.

Answer (score 0):

is this what are you looking for?

```html
<style>
      body,html{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      .loadingcontainer{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 50vh;
        padding-top: 50vh;
        text-align: center;
      }
      #loader {
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
        border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 5px solid #1976d2;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
       -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      }
      #loadingMsg{
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
      
      @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="loadingcontainer">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="loadingMsg">Making stuff up. Please wait... </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert position only for container, like this :

```
.loadingcontainer {

    position:absolute; 

    top: 50%;

    left: 50%;

    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

}
```

for setting text center use :

```
#loader {

    margin: auto;

    //Other codes...

}
```

```css
.loadingcontainer {
        position:absolute; 
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      }
      
      #loader {
        border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 5px solid #1976d2;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
       -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
       animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
       margin: auto;
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
      
      @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
```

```html
 <div class="loadingcontainer">
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <div id="loadingMsg" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color:black;">Making stuff up. Please wait... </div>
    </div>
```